# Trying to open .eml files loads the entire email client, not the file

Tags: windows-xp, outlook-express

I use Outlook Express on WXP with SP3. I'd been trying different email clients that associated .eml files with them, and eventually used folder options to change the association back to OE. At first, the files opened normally, but after a short while the entire program started loading instead of the file. If I associate .eml files with the other email client still on my computer, it works fine. Why this is happening, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly there is a missing parameter in the registry and just only application starts, not the clicked .eml files. The exact commandline shoud be:

```
"fullpath\to\outlookexpress.EXE" /eml "%1
```

Default; it would be:

```
"C:\Program Files\Outlook Express\MSIMN.EXE" /eml:%1
```

or

```
"C:\Program Files\Outlook Express\MSIMN.EXE" /eml "%1"
```

Notice the /eml parameter, it might be missing in your registry.

> If EML files will not open in Outlook Express, try the following:
>
> Open My Computer. Select Folder Options from the Tools menu. Click the
>   File Types tab. Under Registered file types, select EML Outlook
>   Express Mail Message, then click Advanced. Click Open, then click
>   Edit. Type the following line in the "Application used to perform
>   action" box: "C:\Program Files\Outlook Express\MSIMN.EXE" /eml:%1
>   Click OK twice, then close the window.

Comment: Adding /eml to the command line in edit file type worked - thanks!

Comment: Welcome! And then please mark as "Anser" to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Try [re-installing OE](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=318378#XSLTH3126121123120121120120):

```
msimn /reg
regsvr32 urlmon.dll
regsvr32 mshtml.dll
regsvr32 shdocvw.dll 
regsvr32 browseui.dll 
regsvr32 msjava.dll
```